# Continue AJAX request after page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple question, but can't find a quick answer. Maybe somebody here can help me.

If I trigger an AJAX request on my HTML page with jQuery and then trigger a refresh while the AJAX request isn't finished yet, does the AJAX request stop? Or does it continue on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it depends on the server software and the language the server script is written in.

Comment: Ajax request continuous its execution and then after your page refresh will be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax request will stop. Whether or not your server processes the request will depend on whether or not the server completely received the request before it was stopped.

This is a case where it is ok to use `async: false` to get the behaviour you want. However, it would be better to just wait to do the refresh until the ajax is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on whether or not a session was started on the ajax page.

If yes then the php will 'block' until the ajax request was completed and the page refresh will not occur until such time.

You can however prevent this 'blocking behavior' with `session_write_close();` which will leave the session open for reading but not writing

Comment: php can't cause an ajax request to be synchronous. The blocking behavior you are describing doesn't stop the page from refreshing.

Comment: I've found php to be synchronous in some cases, eg: `header("Content-type: video/avi"); echo file_get_contents($path . $file);` if the session is open no further requests will be honored until the file is delivered

Answer (score 0):

it will be aborted immediately from client side, but it could make changes to database if it having some update operations